# What is the best way to convert a monochrome image to a binary string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, encryption, binary

Currently my plan is to use `numpy.ndarray.tolist(numpy.asarray(img))` and iterate through every third element (since each pixel is represented as three RGB integers), checking if it is zero or not to generate a binary string. I'm sure there must be a better way to do this, I'm just not sure what...

Answer (score 1):

Numpy and Pillow are very good friends. You can convert a pillow image to a numpy array simply by providing the image as an argument:

```
 from PIL import Image 
 import numpy as np

 path = "path\to\image.jpg"
 image_file = Image.open(path) 
 bilevel_img = image_file.convert('1')
 data_array = np.array(bilevel_img)
 print(data_array)
```

Note that "1" mode is bilevel, so you will get a True / False array.

You may be a lot better off with grayscale mode, and then bileveling at a threshold you define:

```
 gray = np.array(img.convert("L"))
 print(gray)
 threshold = 128 # cutoff between 0 and 255
 bilevel_array = (gray > threshold).astype(int)
 print(bilevel_array)
```

This gives you a binary array!

Comment: Thank you for your help, although I did need a different solution I still learnt a bit from your response!

Answer (score 0):

Another concise way would be the following, using Pillow and numpy:

```py
image = Image.open(image_path).convert('1')
bytes(np.packbits(np.array(image)))
```